# How to store multiple data in cache c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching

Hi I have one user control which I am calling multiple times in particular page, and below is the code for that

```
 private void BindMenu()
        {
            string menuContent = (string)Cache[_CacheKey];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuContent))
            {                
                menuContent = GenerateMenu(CategoryId, 1);             
                Cache.Add(_CacheKey, menuContent, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            }
            phMenu.Text = menuContent;
        }
```

Now the Bind menu is called multiple times as I am passing different category Id like 1,2,3.

But once the category Id of 1 is passed it stores it data in cache and then after when user control is repeated on same page it always shows stored data as show in cache.

I had tried removing cache logic and the data reflect is user control shows as per my result but it is increasing the page loading time.

**Any Help?**

**Resolved Issue**

```
 private void BindMenu()
        {
            string menuContent = (string)Cache[_CacheKey+Convert.ToString(CategoryId)];
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuContent))
            {                
                menuContent = GenerateMenu(CategoryId, 1);             
                Cache.Add(_CacheKey+Convert.ToString(CategoryId), menuContent, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            }
            phMenu.Text = menuContent;
        }
```

Comment: What key are you Using for the cache?

Comment: I had never used cache.
And cache key must be passing same

Comment: @PeterBons in case if cash key is passing different in that case can this work?

Comment: Yes, per category for example. Like `_CacheKey + CategoryId.ToString()`

Comment: Can you provide me with some example as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using cache to pass parameters to a web user control is a bad idea.

You need to use **properties**.

Declare a `public int` variable in the User Control's' code, and in its `set` function, use the `value` passed.

In the user control's code behind:

```
// Declare a public property
public int CategoryId 
{ 
   set
   {
       // use the value keyword to get the value passed from the main page:
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(menuContent))
       {                
           menuContent = GenerateMenu(value, 1);  
           phMenu.Text = menuContent;             
       }
   }
}
```

In the calling (containing) page's code:

```
UserControl1.CategoryId = 1;
UserControl2.CategoryId = 2;
....
```

Comment: I told that I had tried remving cache and that is working fine but it is taking more loading time, the record fetched is almost 500 to 1000